# PHP API Request with Large Array Parameter

Tags: php, rest, request, http-post, httprequest

My company is developing an API for reporting data to our stakeholders. The user is able to log in and see numerous data sets on several different pages. One caveat is that the user who is logged in may have other 'users' who earned them compensation in some way and they see this data on each individual page.

The downfall is that some users can have over 2,000 associated users that they see data for. The business requirement was to have these 'sub users' placed into a drop down box and allow the logged in user to check/uncheck to filter in and out for the data set. The parameters for one of our endpoints are:

```
user     => string
subUsers => array
dates    => array
```

The dates array consists of a 'From' and 'To' date to allow the user to look at historical reporting. Since this is all just reporting, the queries are just select statements. The queries themselves appear to run fine (under 1 second). However, the actual request through the API itself takes a long time to pass. We recently had to change the 'GET' requests to 'POST' requests because of the size for some of our users' 'Sub User' array. We also had to increase the max_input_vars from the 1,000 default to 5,000. That was still not enough for some so we increased to 10,000. This is only a temporary solution and cannot be thought of as a viable option to keep upping the max_input_vars. However, this update only allowed the API to complete processing but did not speed it up whatsoever.

Are there any recommendations or best practices when dealing with parameters that can likely contain such large arrays? Any advice or feedback on how to best handle this type of requirement would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

max_input_vars and max_input_time affect the $_POST variable in an unexpected way. If the time needed to post the data is bigger than max_input_time, $_POST will start missing values. Same happens for max_input_vars.

One solution to this would be to not post the array as an array, but encode it as string when you post it( using serialize / json_encode) and decode it in the API. This should give you a speed boost.